# What happens if my companion hates me?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

If I continually lose affection points with my companion, what happens? Does she run-away, drop dead, turn on me and fight to the death?

Comment: I think you can piss them off enough so they will go away, no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UPDATE:

Apparently at some point, a patch has been applied to the game that now allows companions affection to be negative. See other answers for details. (I haven't confirmed this or I'd put the details in this answer.)

ORIGINAL:

No. Your companion's Affection can not go below the initial starting value, indicating neutral.

If you're on an RP server, feel free to role play their hatred towards you by staging a fight with them yourself, then never summoning them again after you betray them and let them die in a fight you tell them to start as you run away laughing at their demise.

Otherwise, (seriously) the benefit of having high Affection with a particular companion increases their chances of crafting and mission successes, yields better quality results and opens up better gear.

Comment: Haha, we should get dark side points for betraying them. I read after asking the question higher affections will also decrease crafting and mission times.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what happens but if you get Khem Vhal mad, he will get a broken heart sign next to his affiliation. I'm not sure what that actually does but, he can start to go negative on you.

Answer (score 3):

You can in fact get a negative score. The heart will turn red and the number of negative points are indicated by a minus sign before the number.

Answer (score 2):

In 4.0, Affection has been replaced with Influence.  As with Affection, Influence is completely orthogonal to whether your companions *actually* like you and your choices — it simply indicates that you've had some affect on them.  Unlike Affection, however, it can only increase — so decisions that they don't like still increase it.  You can't have negative Influence, and it goes from 1-50 (with increasing amounts required to advance a level as you go on).

In pre Fallen Empire content, companions behave the same as before — only your personal conversations *with them alone* actually affects how they feel about you.  What you do in quests and other conversations does not change whether you can romance them, and so on.

In Fallen Empire and beyond, this is no longer true.  Your story decisions now affect how your companions feel about you and whether you can romance them, and it won't always be clear whether a given choice will have unintended consequences down the line.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue that comes if the affection rate goes ***too negative/low*** is that it takes longer to regain their affection so that you can unlock the legacy buffs, which unlock when their affection hits ***10,000***. If you don't care about those buffs, then there shouldn't be a big problem.

Then again, I've never seen a ***-10000*** companion before so I'm not sure if they try to kill you, commit suicide, leave, or what at that point.